# How to convert the value from string to date for saving the data?

Tags: html

I cannot store date value in database if it's string, how can i convert it to date format?

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' id="startDate" data-bind="value: startDate()" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span onclick="startToday()">Today</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Give use more informations. PHP? Type of Database? Some severside code?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use `<input type="date">` and convert it using the JavaScript [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
function parse() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value.split("-");

  var date;
  if (startDate.length == 3) date = new Date(startDate[0], startDate[1], startDate[2]);
  else date = new Date();

  console.log("Formated:", date);
  console.log("Timestamp:", date.valueOf() / 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='date' id="startDate" data-bind="value: startDate()" class="form-control" value="2018-03-21" oninput="parse()" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span onclick="startToday()">Today</span>
  </span>
</div>
```